# JSON Decode elements in file

Tags: php, json

Hi I am currently working on stripping out a json file and putting the elements into a database there are 26 entries in the json file using the following code I have been able to map the majority of the entries but am now in a position whereby certain elements in the json only occur in certain entries eg tags in the first 2 entries has a Name and cirrushq_id field but from the 3rd entry down has only a aws:autoscaling:groupName not present in the first 2 entries so my question really is how to modify the php such that it takes into account the fact that there may not be a Name or id for every entry and not subsequently break ?

here is the php

```
<?php 


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","json_map");
$response = array(); 
$res=array(); 
$json = file_get_contents('C:\Users\Richard\Desktop\test.json'); 

if($json!=null){ 
$decoded=json_decode($json,true); 
//$decode= var_dump($decoded); 
//$ss=$decode["array"]; 
//echo $decoded['number']; 

if(is_array($decoded["configurationItems"])) 
{ 
foreach($decoded["configurationItems"] as $configurationItems) 
//for($i=0;$i>sizeof($decoded["configurationItems"]);$i++) 

 { 




$Name=$configurationItems["tags"]["Name"]; 
echo "Name:",$Name,"<br />"; 


$cirrushq_id=$configurationItems["tags"]["cirrushq_id"]; 
echo "cirrushq_id:",$cirrushq_id,"<br />"; 

$awsautoscalinggroupName= $configurationItems["tags"]["aws:autoscaling:groupName"]; 
 echo "aws:autoscaling:groupName:",$awsautoscalinggroupName,"<br />"; 







$result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO     tag(name, cirrushq_id, aws_autoscaling_group_name)


VALUES('$Name','$cirrushq_id', '$awsautoscalinggroupName')")or die("Insert Failed ".((is_object($con)) ? mysqli_error($con) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));; 

}// check if row inserted or not 
if ($result) { 
    // successfully inserted into database 
    $response["code"] = 1; 
    $response["message"] = "successfully stored tags "; 

    // echoing JSON response 
    echo json_encode($response); 
} else { 
    // failed to insert row 
    $response["code"] = 2; 
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred."; 

    // echoing JSON response 
    echo json_encode($response); 
} 

} 
} 



  ?>
```

and the json

```
 {  
 "fileVersion":"1.0",
 "configurationItems":[  
   {  
     "configurationItemVersion":"1.0",
     "configurationItemCaptureTime":"2014-12-05T10:22:51.751Z",
     "configurationStateId":1,
     "relatedEvents":[  ],
     "awsAccountId":"",
     "configurationItemStatus":"ResourceDiscovered",
     "resourceId":"",
     "ARN":"",
     "awsRegion":"us-east-1",
     "availabilityZone":"us-east-1b",
     "configurationStateMd5Hash":"",
     "resourceType":"AWS::EC2::Instance",
     "resourceCreationTime":"2014-01-06T10:37:37.000Z",
     "tags":{  
        "Name":"dbn.prod-us.wordeo.com",
        "cirrushq_id":"instance_20"
     },
```

as above for 2nd entry

3rd entry the same down to tags as follows

```
"tags":{  
        "aws:autoscaling:groupName":"ES-PROD-US-03-01-14"
     },
```

using isset method as per answer

```
<?php 


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","json_map");
$response = array(); 
$res=array(); 
$json = file_get_contents('C:\Users\Richard\Desktop\test.json'); 

if($json!=null){ 
$decoded=json_decode($json,true); 
//$decode= var_dump($decoded); 
//$ss=$decode["array"]; 
//echo $decoded['number']; 

if(is_array($decoded["configurationItems"])) 
{ 
foreach($decoded["configurationItems"] as $configurationItems) 
//for($i=0;$i>sizeof($decoded["configurationItems"]);$i++) 

$tags=$configurationItems["tags"];
if(isset($tags["Name"]) && isset($tags["cirrushq_id"])){
$Name=$tags["Name"]; 
echo "Name:",$Name,"<br />"; 
$cirrushq_id=$tags["cirrushq_id"]; 
echo "cirrushq_id:",$cirrushq_id,"<br />"; 
$awsautoscalinggroupName= isset($tags["aws:autoscaling:groupName"]) ?
                              $tags["aws:autoscaling:groupName"] : ''; 
echo "aws:autoscaling:groupName:",$awsautoscalinggroupName,"<br />"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tag(name, cirrushq_id, aws_autoscaling_group_name)
        VALUES('$Name','$cirrushq_id', '$awsautoscalinggroupName')"); 

}// check if row inserted or not 
if ($result) { 
    // successfully inserted into database 
    $response["code"] = 1; 
    $response["message"] = "successfully stored tags "; 

    // echoing JSON response 
    echo json_encode($response); 
} else { 
    // failed to insert row 
    $response["code"] = 2; 
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred."; 

    // echoing JSON response 
    echo json_encode($response); 
} 

} 
}
```

?>

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but I strongly advice you to stop using mysqli functions. Use PDO library to query your database: http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check the name or id exists or not.
Change the php foreach loop code like,

```
$tags=$configurationItems["tags"];
if(isset($tags["Name"]) && isset($tags["cirrushq_id"])){
    $Name=$tags["Name"]; 
    echo "Name:",$Name,"<br />"; 
    $cirrushq_id=$tags["cirrushq_id"]; 
    echo "cirrushq_id:",$cirrushq_id,"<br />"; 
    $awsautoscalinggroupName= isset($tags["aws:autoscaling:groupName"]) ?
                                  $tags["aws:autoscaling:groupName"] : ''; 
    echo "aws:autoscaling:groupName:",$awsautoscalinggroupName,"<br />"; 
    // remove the die if there is any error then it will go forward
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tag(name, cirrushq_id, aws_autoscaling_group_name)
            VALUES('$Name','$cirrushq_id', '$awsautoscalinggroupName')");
```

Comment: thank you for your response unfortunately when I run your code  the database is not populating yet still delivers updated successfully message with or without the die any ideas ? plus it is not echoing out the values just the message

Comment: Is it echoing `name, id, etc`?

Comment: Huh!!! Then check are you getting `$tags` or not, check your loop is working or not?

Comment: when I preview my code in the ide I get Undefined variable: result I have edited question to show your implemented code I am probably doing something silly

Comment: Its because it is not entered in the loop and not inserted any thing in database. To remove the error just add `$result='';` after `$json = file_get_contents('C:\Users\Richard\Desktop\test.json'); `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69213/discussion-between-richard-hewitt-and-rohan-kumar).

Comment: indeed, my looping was wrong your code was fine thanks again !